# Kivy Clock stops after while on its own

Tags: python, kivy

I have simple OSD app made with python and kivy, running on raspberry. All it does it start clock that periodically pulls data from DB and update Label.text...

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
import MySQLdb

class OSDBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_stats, 20)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_stats, 0.1)

    def update_stats(self, *args):
        try:
            self.active = []
            self.db = MySQLdb.connect(<DB connect info here>)

            self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
            self.cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
            self.cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
            self.cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
            self.cursor.execute('SELECT domain FROM domain_info')

            self.total_domains = self.cursor.rowcount

            self.cursor.execute('SELECT domain FROM domain_list WHERE checked="" OR checked="Update"')

            self.for_update_domains = self.cursor.rowcount

            self.db.close()

            self.ids.marked_update.text=str(self.for_update_domains)

        except:
            pass


class osdApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'OSD'
        return OSDBoxLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    osdApp().run()
```

Evrything works fine, for a while... but after some time it stops... app does not crash, it still displays on LCD... but the update is no longer executed... I need to kill it and start again. No error in kivy log.

I suspect that the clock just hang, or have some default expiration ?

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: added whole code

Comment: Why do not you print the exception?, maybe the error is not in Clock but in the connection to the database.

Comment: but wouldn't it just pass if error occur, and then try again in next run ? ( i will add print exception to the code juse to check )

Comment: mmm, have you tried it on your pc?

Comment: not yet, but I think I have found the issue, need to test it

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issues was that the SBC ( raspberry ) periodically switched VPN connection, which caused to connection to MYSQL hang so self.db.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=20') needs to be set to some small time to time out the connection.. ( or stop switching VPNs in my case ) its running fine now for over 24hours ! :)